# Memory Leak in Windows 7 and I need help troubleshooting

Tags: windows-7, memory, troubleshooting, memory-leaks

So, about a week ago I got a blue screen while watching a youtube video (it was the only active program open) and I've been experiencing trouble ever since.

The file that caused the blue screen was a corrupt driver, and I updated it. No more blue screens to report.

Now my issue seems like a memory leak. Slowly, over about an hour, the RAM usage will climb from 2GB at boot, to 13.8GB out of 16GB. At which point the system becomes unresponsive. After becoming unresponsive, the display driver crashes (which clears up about 1GB of RAM) then it becomes unresponsive again.

Any help would be appreciated, at this point I worry I'll just have to re-install Windows.

Here's a screenshot of the task manager, nothing accounts for the usage:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of Windows Performance Analyzer, How can I find out what the "Unknown" process is?
[image]

Comment: What program or Process was using the Ram? did you look at Taskmanager?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the task manager, nothing accounts for the usage.  [link](http://imgur.com/J1fOCKV)

Comment: Boot into a minimal boot camps configuration(I.e only load your display driver) no applications unless the system won't boot then determine if the memory leak still happens

Comment: The minimal boot showed no signs of a leak, so how can I narrow down what process/driver is the issue (seeing as no process in taskman shows high usage)?

Comment: viewing page faults in process explorer occasionally shows crc32.exe having 9,000,000,000+ page faults... that seems bad right?

Comment: @JamesTuttle - Add each driver you didn't load in that mimimal boot, one by one, until you find the culprit.  Once you find the driver, with the memory leak, update your question.

Comment: Ramhound, thank you for your help! I located the leak and have corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a solution to my problem.  The driver that allows me to use a third party bluetooth fob was the cause of the memory leak.  Configuring my system to only load a single driver, by eliminating each driver one by one,  led me to the solution to my problem.

Comment: Could you perhaps name the driver so that others suffering from the error can more easily find this answer?

Comment: @JamesTuttle please post which driver (and version) it was. This helps other users

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a *clean* install of a corrupt driver, not just an upgrade.

This involves a full removal of all graphics drivers and a new install of your specific driver.
The Display Driver Removal Tool is fantastic at removing all reminance of a driver:
http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html

Then re-download your driver and install as normal

Comment: The leak is still apparent, even after uninstalling the graphics driver. To clarify, the original driver that caused the bluescreen was for my headset. I just uninstalled it entirely.